# Why can't update a value in a child component (with react context) when a provider component parent state change?

Tags: javascript, react-context

I am trying to use React Context in my project. I implemented a provider component and I am consuming the data in two child components. But when I update the state of the Provider component from one of the children, the other child is not re-rendered with the data from the provider component.

I am using these characteristics of React Context to avoid passing the props from component to component. As I have implemented it in the past

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/qzz27x736j)

// Parent Provider

```
const {Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext()

class ShoppingCartProvider extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                  order: {},
                  Total: 0,

            }
      }

      addOrder = (key) => {
            const order = this.state.order
            let totalOrder = this.state.Total
            order[key] = order[key] + 1 || 1
            this.setState({order})
            totalOrder = totalOrder + 1
            this.setState({Total: totalOrder})

      }
      render(){
            return(
                  <Provider value={{
                        order: this.state.order,
                        addOrder: this.addOrder,
                        totalOrder: this.state.Total
                  }}>
                  <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                  </Provider>     
            )
      }
}

export {ShoppingCartProvider, Consumer as ShoppingCartConsumer}
```

// child  that changes the parent state

```
import React, {useContext } from 'react';

const ItemProducto = props =>{
      const {product} = props

      const {addOrder} = useContext(ShoppingCartConsumer)

      return <Grid item>
                 <div css={botonAdd}
                   onClick={()=>{
                        addOrder(product._id)
                  }}>Add</div>
             </Grid>

}



export default ItemProducto
```

//This is not re-rendered when the state in parent component changes

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Header = props =>{      

      const {totalOrder} = useContext(ShoppingCartConsumer)
      const [count, setcount] = useState(totalOrder)

      useEffect(()=>{
            setcount(totalOrder)
      })
      return (
           <div>                                                                
              <Grid item  css={numeroDinero}>{count}</Grid>                                                              
           </div> 

      )
}


export default Header
```

I expect a re-render in Header child when ItemProducto child change a Total state property.

Comment: Please could you reproduce this on codesandbox, I'll be interested in having a look.

Comment: Just share a link in codesandbox of example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your code checks out except one. The `useContext()` expects the actual context as an argument not the consumer. In your case you passed in the consumer by doing this: `export {..., Consumer as ShoppingCartConsumer }`.

All you need to do to fix the issue is this:
In `ShoppingCartContext` change:

`const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext()` to

`const ShoppingCartContext = React.createContext();`.

And in your `render`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ShoppingCartContext.Provider
        value={{
          order: this.state.order,
          addOrder: this.addOrder,
          totalOrder: this.state.Total
        }}
      >
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
    );
  }
```

Then change your export to: `export { ShoppingCartProvider, ShoppingCartContext };`

Modify the imports in the `Header` and `ItemProducto` accordingly, and do not forget to pass `ShoppingCartContext` to their respective `useContext()`s.

For more info on `useContext` see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

[image: Edit context and hooks]